# Sequence of Rest and Soap calls to get the final result using Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns, soap, completable-future

I have to make a sequence of calls like a chain to other microservices to get the final result.

Of these calls, some are SOAP and some REST.

Is there any good design pattern to chain these calls and handle exceptions using synchronous.

If I go with Asynchronous then CompletableFuture chain will be the right choice for SOAP calls?

For example

```
 CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getEmp())
    .thenApply(emp -> {
        // handle soap client call
        return soapClientService.getDepartmentResponse();
    })
    .thenApply(dept -> {            
        return restTemplateService.getRestDeptAPICalls();
    })
    .handle((result, exception) -> {
        // handle exception and result
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you can use Pipeline design pattern.

1. Pipe A calls Rest end-point A, map the response to a Message and return the
   message.
2. Pipe B which implements a Soap service B, transforms the resulting message. It creates and return a new and different message.
3. Pipe C which implements a Rest end-point C, calls Soap service B using the
       new message as input . It creates a new message from the result,
       adds a flag and return the message.
4. And so on...

You can have something like that:

```
public interface Pipe{
    void chain(Message input, Pipeline pipeline);
}

public abstract class RestCallPipe implements Pipe {

   private RestTemplate restTemplate;

   public RestCallPipe (String url){
      this.restTemplate=new RestTemplate(url);
   }

   public void chain(Message input, Pipeline pipeline){
      try {
        Response response = restTemplate.exchange(....,input,Response.class);
        Message output = onSuccess(response, input);
        pipeline.next(output);
      }catch(Exception exception){
        onError(exception, input);
       //Maybe, we can continue 
       //with an alternative message
      }
   }       

   public abstract Message onSuccess(Response response, Message originalMessage);
   public abstract void onError(Throwable error, Message input);    
 }


public abstract class SoapCallPipe implements Pipe {

   public void chain(Message input, Pipeline pipeline){
      try {
        // Perform your Soap call and get a response
        Message output = onSuccess(response, input);
        pipeline.next(output);
      }catch(Exception exception){
        onError(exception, input);
       //Maybe, we can continue 
       //with an alternative message
      }
   }       

   public abstract Message onSuccess(Response response, Message originalMessage);
   public abstract void onError(Throwable error, Message input);    
 }


public interface Message {
    public Object get(String key);
}
public class MessageImpl implements Message {
    private final Map<String, Object> index;
    public MessageImpl(){...}
    public void set(String key, Objetc value){...}
    public Object get(String key){...}
}
```

The `Pipeline` is a chain of Pipes. Each pipe executes a command and tell the pipeline to continue with a new message.

Hope that helps.